# How to edit the entire file after match a grep pattern?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

To simplify, I want to edit the whole file after matched pattern, example of a file:

```
$ cat file
ip=x.x.x.a
mask=255.0.0.0
host=a
ip=x.x.x.b
mask=255.0.0.0
host=b
ip=x.x.x.c
mask=255.0.0.0
host=c
ip=x.x.x.x
blahblah
mask=255.0.0.0
host=d
```

Let's suppose that I want to edit the IP from host c, but note that this may be variable, so I don't know this value. If I `grep host c` and use the `-B2` to print the lines I can't edit it in the original file! Another point the line may not have the same structure, that's the case of host d, between `ip` and `mask` info there's some text, so I can't assume that the IP pattern always will be 2 lines before my search pattern.

Resuming, I can't grep the IP directly because I don't know it, instead I need to search for host, and edit the line before this match to change the value of IP. How can I do this?

Comment: So what _can_ you know? Can you be sure that each hosts's entry will always start with the `ip=` line? And what operating system are you using? Can we assume GNU tools (default on Linux)?

Comment: yes, each "block" contains at least these 3 information ( ip, mask and host ), but it may contains another information between these 3. And the order is always the same ( ip, mask, host ) they don't change, but I don't want to edit by it's line number. Yes it's a Linux OS Debian. My pattern search needs to be by the host. For example, if I search for `host=c` I need to change the IP that is equals x.x.x.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will change the IP associated with host `c` to `1.2.3.4`:

```
$ sed 's/^ip/\nip/' file | perl -00pe 'if(/\nhost=c\n/){s/ip=\S+/ip=1.2.3.4/} s/\n\n/\n/' 
ip=x.x.x.a
mask=255.0.0.0
host=a
ip=x.x.x.b
mask=255.0.0.0
host=b
ip=1.2.3.4
mask=255.0.0.0
host=c
ip=x.x.x.x
blahblah
mask=255.0.0.0
host=d
```

#### Explanation:

- `sed 's/^ip/\nip/' file` : add an extra newline (`\n`) to each line beginning with `ip`. I think this might not work with all implementations of `sed`, so if yours doesn't support this, replace the `sed` command with `perl -pe 's/^ip/\nip/'`. We need this in order to use Perl's "paragraph mode" (seen below).
- `perl -00pe` : the `-00` makes perl run in "paragraph mode" where a "line" is defined by two consecutive newlines. This enables us to treat each host's block as a single "line". The `-pe` means "print each line after applying the script given by `-e` to it".
- `if(/\nhost=c\n/){s/ip=\S+/ip=1.2.3.4/}` : if this "line" (section) matches a newline followed by the string `host=c` and then another newline, then replace `ip=` and 1 or more non-whitespace characters (`\S+`) following it with `ip=1.2.3.4`.
- `s/\n\n/\n/` replace each pair of newlines with a single newline to get the original file's format back.

If you want this to change the file in place, you can use:

```
tmp=$(mktemp); sed 's/^ip/\nip/' file > $tmp; 
perl -00pe 'if(/\nhost=c\n/){s/ip=\S+/ip=1.2.3.4/} s/\n\n/\n/' $tmp > file
```

Comment: great! worked fine, and I tested with time and got better time.

Answer (score 4):

This gets a lot easier if you go through the file backwards.  Fortunately, you can do so easily with `tac` (which happens to be `cat` backwards).  We can then use a relatively simple `awk` script to look for your `host`, and change only its `ip`:

```
$ tac input | awk -v OFS="=" -v myip="changed_address" -v myhost="d" -F"=" '$1 == "host" { if( $2 == myhost ) { sw = "on" } else { sw="off" } } sw == "on" && $1 == "ip" { $2=myip } { print $0 }' | tac
ip=x.x.x.a
mask=255.0.0.0
host=a
ip=x.x.x.b
mask=255.0.0.0
host=b
ip=x.x.x.c
mask=255.0.0.0
host=c
ip=changed_address
blahblah
mask=255.0.0.0
host=d
```

I shall explain in detail how the `awk` works:

First, we declare a few variables: one each for the `host` and new value for the `ip`:

```
-v myip="changed_address" -v myhost="d"
```

Further, we declare the field separator for the input and output:

```
-v OFS="=" -F"="
```

Now, the actual `awk` script itself:

```
$1 == "host" {             // If we see the "host" line..
  if( $2 == myhost ) {     // And it matches the one we're looking for..
    sw = "on"              // Set a flag to swap the next IP
  } else { 
    sw="off"               // Otherwise, unset the flag
  }
} 

sw == "on" && $1 == "ip" { // If the flag is set and this is an IP line.. 
    $2=myip                // Swap in the new IP 
}

{
   print $0                // Finally, print out the processed line
}
```

Once that's all done, we just use `tac` again to re-reverse it, making it forwards again.

Comment: Worked great too, but I got better performance with perl command.

Answer (score 3):

I know you are expecting something very fast, and simple like a one-line sed command or a smart awk code, but if you don't care...

```
#!/bin/bash
#Note: Adjusted to run with a posix shell (tested in dash)
filename='file'
newip='127.0.0.1'
hostchar='d'

tac "$filename" | while IFS= read -r line ; do 
     case $line in 
          host=${hostchar})  
              flag=on 
          ;;
          host=*)
              flag=off
          ;;
     esac
     if [ "$flag" = "on" ]; then
     case $line in 
          ip=*) 
              echo ip=$newip
              continue 
          ;; 
          #you can replace more variables at once by adding it here
          #in the same standard. 
          #for ex: mask=*) echo mask=$newmask; continue ;; etc...
     esac  
     fi
     echo $line 
done | tac
```

Results:

```
ip=x.x.x.a
mask=255.0.0.0
host=a
ip=x.x.x.b
mask=255.0.0.0
host=b
ip=x.x.x.c
mask=255.0.0.0
host=c
ip=127.0.0.1
blahblah
mask=255.0.0.0
host=d
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to send some commands to `ed`:

```
h=c
ed -s file <<< $'/^host='"${h}"$'$\n?^ip=\nc\nip=new.ip.here\n.\nw\nq' > /dev/null
```

The basic idea is to edit the file and pipe in a newline-separated list of commands (in two ANSI C quote strings `$' ... '`) that search for the given host (in variable `$h`), then search backwards for a line that begins with `ip=`, then change that line to be something new, then save and quit `ed`. Broken out by newlines (`\n`), the commands are:

1. `/^host=` ... `$h` `$` -- start a search (`/`) for the string `host=` at the beginning of the line (`^`), followed by the contents of `$h`, and ending the line (`$`).  Relax the end-of-line requirement if your host isn't a complete match.
2. `?^ip=` -- Now that we're on the matching line, search backwards for the text `ip=` at the beginning of a line.
3. `c` -- change this line
4. insert the text `ip=new.ip.here`
5. `.` -- end the insertion text
6. `w` -- write the file to disk
7. `q` -- quit ed

Invoking ed with `-s` silences the byte-count it emits when opening and saving the file. Redirecting the entire command to `/dev/null` silences the default output when `ed` finds the `host=` and `ip=` lines we're searching for.

Comment: This is genious! A stepwise approach, using an automated editor more intuitive for complex cases than regular expressions. And people are still arguing whether Vim or Emacs is king, right :D?

A bit less convenient, but inspired by the answer, here is a solution using vim:
`vim -c 'execute "normal /host=d\<Enter>?^ip=\<Enter>f=lCnew_ip_for_c\<Esc>:wq\<Enter>"' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v host=c -v newip=zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz '$0 ~ "^host=" host "$" { print; getline; $0 = sprintf("ip=%s\s", newip) }; 1' file
ip=x.x.x.a
mask=255.0.0.0
host=a
ip=x.x.x.b
mask=255.0.0.0
host=b
ip=x.x.x.c
mask=255.0.0.0
host=c
ip=zzz.zzz.zzz.zzzs
blahblah
mask=255.0.0.0
host=d
```

This assumes that you'd like to change the IP address of some named host and that the IP address line is always occurring after the `host=` line for that host.

The `awk` program takes the host name and the new IP address on the command line by setting the two `awk` variables `host` and `newip`.  The code then locates the `host=` line corresponding to the given hostname, reads and discards the following line (the `ip=` line) and creates a new `ip=` line with the new IP address.  The data (modified or not) is outputted by the trailing `1` in the program.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively short solution using negative lookahead assertions in a perl regular expression:

`perl -p0e 's/(ip=)[^\n]*((?:(?!ip=).)*?host=c)/\1new_ip_for_host_c\2/gs' hosts.txt`

## Explanation:

First, a print-loop is used using the `-p` option. This iterates through lines of a file provided as argument to `perl` and prints them. If the line is changed, the changed variant is printed, as with `sed`.

The file contents are not actually treated as separate lines, the `-p` option merely serves to make `perl` read in the file at once and use the contents as the default string to match in, without using a variable. This is achieved via the `-0` option, which makes `perl` treat multiline input as a single line, substituting newline characters by null bytes.

In the pattern, parts excluding the value to be changed are saved.

The value is recognized as anything until the next newline, which I assume is understood as the next null-byte in this situation. Someone who knows this could perhaps explain.

Then, using a negative lookahead assertion, all characters are matched that are not preceded by an `ip=` part, until the `host=d` part is encountered. This is necessary, otherwise perl would prefer the left-most match over the shortest, and would match from the very first `ip=` to the required `host=c` part.

The characters not preceded by `ip=` are matched in a non-greedy manner, otherwise again, the match would encompass everything from the first `ip=` until `host=c`, because by default, the longest match is preferred.
In other terms, this ensures that text is matched in sections terminated by `host=c`, and started by the `ip=` segment that is closest above `host=c`, not furthest.

The character restricted by the negative lookahead expression inside the `(?:)` construct. It denotes a non-capturing group, meaning that it won't count toward the total number of backreferences in the substitution string.
Grouping is used so the `*` sign can properly quantify the whole negative lookahead - dot character combo as a single atom.
In the example, backreferences range from `\1` - `\2`, whilst without the non-capturing group, they would be `\1` - `\3`, with `\3` denoting the nested group.

The backreferences `\1` and `\2` in the substitution string are the matched parts of the section that enclose exactly the ip address for the host found in the matched section.

The ip address will thus be substituted by `new_ip_for_host_c`.

## General blablablah:

I am not sure if the data format was the OP's choice, just putting this out in general: it is better to store such simple data in such a manner that records are separated by newlines, i.e. there are no multiline records.
Refer to the format of /etc/passwd .
Most standard Unix filters are line-oriented, and data manipulation is much easier if you follow "da Unix wae".
If your data is more complex (nested data items, etc.), you are better off using a format such as JSON and manipulating it with a proper parser.